# Pytrend: TrendReq "Google returned a response with code 429"

Tags: python

I'm trying to get some info about around 50 words with Pytrends. First I was getting a 400 error and found out I was searching for too many words, I reduced it to only 5 words (I tried from 1 to 5 words actually), but
every time I get the error "Google returned a response with code 429".

This is the code I'm actually trying. I already tried to change the `hl` and `geo` to US, together with the `gprop`.
I tried it for 2 days, once I read that the error could be the many times requested.

```
pytrends = TrendReq(hl="pt-BR", tz="360", retries=10, backoff_factor=0.5)
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list[0:5], cat=0, timeframe="today 12-m",geo="BR",gprop="")
df = pytrends.interest_over_time()
```